# Where's the contradiction in this shoe?

Tags: phoenix-wright-ace-attorney

I'm playing through the original Phoenix Wright game, and I'm stuck on a particular part of the "Rise from the Ashes" case. No matter what I do (raise objections, press the witness, etc), everything keeps coming back to this shoe:

[image: Judge: "Show us the problem with this evidence!" (White Shoe)]

But no matter what part of the shoe I point to, nobody seems convinced of anything:

[image: Edgeworth: "Take that finger and point it at your own head, Mr. Wright."]

What am I missing? Is there a contradiction in the victim's shoe, and if so where? I would have just Googled it, but I'm afraid if I do I'll end up getting a whole lot more information than I'm looking for and whole case will be spoiled for me.

I should also note that in the past I've experience some difficulties with the whole 3D evidence examination system in this game. It seems like the targetable areas of the evidence are very tiny and its often been very hard for me to get the game to acknowledge that I am indeed pointing at the correct part of the evidence. So if there is a contradiction I'd appreciate it if you'd be very precise in your description of where it is. Thanks for your help! ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rotate the shoe. Point out the blood on its soles.

Comment: I had to try it several times, but that eventually worked. Thanks!